# Extract metadata about table using BigQuery Client API

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a table in a BigQuery dataset and I'm trying to find out when the table was last modified via the BigQuery client API.

I have tried (in Python)

```
from gcloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client(project="my_project")
dataset = client.dataset("my_dataset")
tables = dataset.list_tables()
table = tables[0][5]  # Extract the table that I want
```

I can check that I've got the right table by running `print(table.name)`, however I don't know how to get the table metadata. In particular, I want to know how to find out when the table was last modified.

Although, I've written the above in Python (I'm more familiar with it than other programming languages) I don't mind if the answer is in Python or Javascript (I think I'm going to have to implement it in the latter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the hood, `tables = dataset.list_tables()` is making an API request to [Tables.list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/list). The result of this request does not contain all the table meta information - like last modified for example.

The [Tables.get](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/get) API request is needed for this type of table information. To make this request you need to call `reload()` on the table. For example:

```
bigquery_service = bigquery.Client()
dataset = bigquery_service.dataset("<your-dataset>")
tables = dataset.list_tables()
for table in tables:
   table.reload()
   print(table.modified)
```

In my test/dataset, this prints:

```
2016-12-30 08:57:15.679000+00:00
2016-12-18 23:57:24.570000+00:00
2016-12-19 05:18:28.371000+00:00
```

See [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/2756) (Github) and [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery-table.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table.reload) (Python docs) for more details.

Comment: This _almost_ works. The only difference is that `dataset.list_tables()` returns a tuple (for me at least), the first argument of which is the list of tables. Hence the modification I used was `tables = dataset.list_tables()[0]`

Comment: I'm using Python v2.7.13 and gcloud v0.18.3